# Reconocer enter para enviar y no escribir nueva linea

Tags: angularjs

Como se puede reconocer con angular la tecla enter para enviar el mensaje en un textArea y no escribir nueva linea?

mi problema consiste en que cuando apreto enter en el chat que hice, primero se escribe nueva linea y pasa pocos milessegundos y se envia el mensaje, pero yo no quiero que se escriba la nueva linea

```
function onWritten($event) {
 if($event.keyCode==13){
   enviarMensaje();
 }
}
```

> resumen: la tecla enter debe funcionar solo para enviar el mensaje y
>   no para escribir nueva linea

Answer (score 1):

Podés escuchar en el keydown event y frenar la propagación del evento cuando se presiona Enter (muy parecido a lo que ya estás haciendo):

Controller

```
$scope.enviar = function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      event.preventDefault();
      // EnviarMensaje();
      console.log($scope.texto);

    }
  }
```

Html

```
ng-keydown='enviar($event)'
```

Ejemplo en plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/V9JGJLPXT4O7PRbTb1gK?p=preview

Comment: el scroll crece por mili segundos

Comment: Fijate si querés agregar esto:<textarea style="overflow:hidden"></textarea> o <textarea style="resize:none"></textarea>, para ocultar el scroll